# C# - Error in adding UPS Tracking API reference

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asp.net-web-api2, ups-api

I am trying to add UPS Tracking API reference to my `Console/Asp.Net Web API` project using the URL `http://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/Track`.

Adding this setting in `App.Config/Web.Config`, but still didn't help:

```
  <add key="AccessLicenseNumber" value="xxxxxxx"/>
  <add key="UserId" value="xxxxxxxx"/>
  <add key="Password" value="xxxxx"/>
```

I can't find any web services at the above URL instead it gives the below message:

```
Service Name: TrackWS
Remote User: null
Server Port: 443
Server Name: wwwcie.ups.com
Servlet Path: /Track
```

Error:

```
There was an error downloading 'http://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/Track/ metadata'. Unable to connect to the remote server
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 153.2.224.76:80
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/Track'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://onlinetools.ups.com/webservices/Track that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks,

WH

Comment: https://www.ups.com/content/au/en/resources/sri/developer_instruct.html

Comment: Maybe try using https.

Comment: @MathewHellums- i tried i but it didn't work either

Comment: I use that API, it requires HTTPS.  Post the error from using HTTPS.

Comment: I still canot even apply for Developer Key because I don't know what my client number is.

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you visit UPS's developer resources site and go ahead and create an account.  It's short and easy to complete.

Once you have an account, you can download sample code and documentation that will guide you step by step on how to integrate with their services.. The documents provided also include the necessary WSDLs that you're looking for to set up a web service reference.

Here's a link to their developer site.
https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/

Hope that helps! Cheers!

Comment: Just a note, most of the sample code does not work... at least that is the case with the .NET samples.